# SAP - Web intelligence Cell Reference

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have created 7 cell references in WEBI with the purpose of averaging seven cells (for a week), the referenced cells contains a percentage value eg 99.25%. However, when I calculate an average on the referenced cell I always return a 1, so it seems the referenced cell is storing as a 1 rather than 99.25%

Any ideas how to navigate this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format the cell. The percentage is being held as 0.9925 and rounding to 1. Right-click on the cell and change the number format to a percentage to make sure this is the case, then fine tune it to display exactly how you want if needed.

Comment: very delayed here - but thanks for your reply!